# Wikipedia corpus for NLP - Cleaned sentences

Tags: nlp, corpus, wikipedia

I can see many wikipedia dumps out there.
I am looking for a wikipedia-made corpus, in which every line is one sentence, without any wikipedia meta tags.

Comment: you can try gensim, from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

Comment: And then what? How do I get the actual sentences?